# Getting a variable value when value is determined afterwards in PHP?

Tags: php, html, email

I know this question seems obvious and redundant, but it was quite difficult to word, I'll try to explain:

I have a "Send to Email" PHP function that also redirects via "Header", looks like this:

```
# -=-=-=- SEND MAIL
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
header('Location: nextpage.php?orderno=' . $orderno);
```

The problem is that the Order Number ($orderno) MUST be defined (it's a random 6-digit number) below into the HTML as the SEND MAIL function gathers the HTML information (including $orderno). But I also need the header to include the same $orderno value to redirect to the next page.

**Now it seems obvious to just change the order of where $orderno is defined, but if I include it in the SEND MAIL function first, the HTML doesn't get it as the function is activated only when the "submit" button below is pressed, but if I include it in the HTML first, PHP doesn't get it.**

I've tried sticking the PHP below the HTML which worked in the sense that $orderno was properly defined, but also brought up obvious PHP Header errors.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue would be outstanding! I've been baffled that I haven't solved such a seemingly simple problem. Thanks!

Comment: Why not just cause a page refresh and have php gather the necessary information from the HTML by using POST, GET, COOKIE or SESSION superglobals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about sessions?

example:

```
session_start();
$orderno =  rand(); // or so...
$_SESSION['orderno'] = $orderno;
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
header('Location: nextpage.php');
```

on `nextpage.php`

```
session_start();
$orderno = $_SESSION['orderno'];
```

Comment: So far your solution was working perfectly, but I've come into a strange instance where the random number isn't the same on the nextpage.php as it was when it was first generated... I can't catch a break, ha!

Comment: After some fumbling with the session_start() placement, your solution was delightful, thank you Gabriel and everybody else who replied!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps could this work:

```
$orderno = "333444333";

$header = 'Location: nextpage.php?orderno=' . $orderno;

$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );


header($header);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps output buffering?

[php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)